# require_dependency is seen but methods not activated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following `universal_methods.rb` file is placed in the controllers directory to contain methods to share across controllers.

```
class UniversalMethods

  def initialise_municipal(user_params)
    user_params = params[:user]
    municipal_via_id = user_params[:municipal_id]
    [...]
  end
end
```

The UserController method is instantiated and contains a method calling the above:

```
require_dependency 'universal_methods'

class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def admin_create
    set_user_login_name
    user_params = params[:user]
    initialise_municipal(user_params)
    [...]
  end
```

I have tested that the application accesses the file (by using just `require` it complains of not finding if).  However, the method is definitely not accessed:
`NoMethodError: undefined method` initialise_municipal' for #UsersController:...`

What is wrong in this syntax / setup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To strictly fix your code you need `UniversalMethods.new.initialise_municipal(user_params)` instead of just `initialise_municipal(user_params)` and there's no need to require the file because everything in `/controllers` is autoloaded.

Another approach for this is with [Concerns](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html). Create a folder `app/controllers/concerns` and put `universal_methods.rb` there.

##### For Rails 6

```
# app/controllers/concerns/universal_methods.rb
module UniversalMethods
 extend ActiveSupport::Concern

 included do
   def initialise_municipal(user_params)
     user_params = params[:user]
     municipal_via_id = user_params[:municipal_id]
   end
 end
end

# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include UniversalMethods
 
  def admin_create
   set_user_login_name
   user_params = params[:user]
   initialise_municipal(user_params)
   [...]
  end
end
```

Comment: Does that have an incidence on tests, as I am getting `Zeitwerk::NameError: expected file [...]universal_methods.rb to define constant UniversalMethods, but didn't` ?

Comment: The one with Concerns?

Comment: that's correct, the now `controllers/concerns/universal_methods.rb` file.

Comment: One sec to test on Rails 6. The answer is R5.

Comment: Updated for r6. Removed the Concerns namespace.